# Laptop LVDS (built-in) monitor not recognized under 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, dkms

I've been running Ubuntu 10.04 on my [Dell Vostro 1220](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/vostronb/en/Vostro1220-spec-sheet-final.pdf) with and without various external VGA devices since 2010 with no problems. I finally tried doing a fresh install of 14.04, and my laptop's built-in monitor would not work unless I added the `nomodeset` option to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

This allowed me to boot, but not change the resolution, nor recognize the external VGA monitor. After googling the problem, I learned that the appropriate driver for my  Mobile Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator X4500MHD seems to be [i915 DRM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel). I also learned that `nomodeset` was likely preventing the display modes on my LVDS screen from being changed and the external VGA from being recognized because it was disabling [KMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Mode_Setting). So, I installed [Intel Linux Graphics Installer 1.0.7](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7), ran it, and after some trial and error changed the boot options in `/etc/default/grub` to say...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 video=VGA-1:1280x1024Me video=LVDS-1:1024x768Me"
```

Now my system recognizes the external VGA just fine, but the built-in LVDS screen is black. Even if I boot up without the VGA plugged in.

Here is the output from `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Output LVDS1 is not disconnected but has no modes 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767 
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm 
     1920x1080      60.0*+    
     1680x1050      60.0      
     1280x1024      75.0 60.0      
     1440x900       59.9      
     1280x960       60.0      
     1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0      
     ... 
     720x400        70.1   
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If I try to add a mode to LVDS1, here is what happens...

```
$ xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1024x768
xrandr: Output LVDS1 is not disconnected but has no modes

$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x768 --pos 0x0 --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --rotate normal
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

$ xrandr --auto
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I really have no idea what I'm doing at this point. Can someone please tell me how I can get Ubuntu 14.04 or some other supported version to recognize both the VGA and LVDS on a laptop with a X4500MHD graphics card, or further steps in troubleshooting this problem, or reading material to understand what it is I'm not getting?

Or, is there a recommended procedure for downgrading from the video drivers and/or kernel in 14.04 to earlier ones that don't break support for my video card?

Thank you.

I don't want to be one of those people with vague questions. Below is all the output I could think of that might be relevant to the problem. I'll be happy to dump anything else anybody thinks would be useful.

Here is what I'm running:

```
echo -n "Release: " && lsb_release -sd && echo -n "Kernel: " || cat /etc/*release && uname -s -r && echo -n "Unity: " && unity --version && echo && /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p -f && echo || echo &&  dpkg -s mesa-utils && echo || echo && echo "Xserver xorg core:" && apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core | grep Installed && echo 

Release: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 
Kernel: Linux 3.13.0-39-generic 
Unity: The program 'unity' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install unity

Package: mesa-utils 
Status: install ok installed 
Priority: optional 
Section: x11 
Installed-Size: 130 
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com> 
Architecture: amd64 
Source: mesa-demos 
Version: 8.1.0-2 
Replaces: xbase-clients (<< 6.8.2-38) 
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libx11-6 
Description: Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities  This package provides several basic GL utilities built by Mesa, including  glxinfo and glxgears. 
Original-Maintainer: Debian X Strike Force <debian-x@lists.debian.org> 
Homepage: http://mesa3d.org/

Xserver xorg core:
   Installed: 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1
```

LVDS claims to be connected.

```
~$ for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done

DP-1: disconnected
LVDS-1: connected
VGA-1: connected
```

There don't seem to be any errors being reported by the GPU:

```
~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_error_state 
no error state collected
~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/i915_error_state 
no error state collected
```

Video-related output from `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02d8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f6c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at efe8 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02d8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f6b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
```

Output from `lshw -C video -sanitize`:

```
*-display:0
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 07
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:45 memory:f6c00000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:efe8(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
     description: Display controller
     product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2.1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
     version: 07
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:f6b00000-f6bfffff
```

Here are the parameters on the i915 video module that as far as I can tell is the module for my chipset...

```
~# for i in /sys/module/i915/parameters/*;do echo ${i}=`cat $i`;done

/sys/module/i915/parameters/disable_display=N
/sys/module/i915/parameters/disable_power_well=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/disable_vtd_wa=N
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_cmd_parser=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc=-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_hangcheck=Y
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_ips=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_ppgtt=0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_psr=0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6=0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/fastboot=N
/sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness=0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_channel_mode=2
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock=0
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_use_ssc=-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/modeset=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/panel_ignore_lid=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/prefault_disable=N
/sys/module/i915/parameters/preliminary_hw_support=1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/reset=Y
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores=-1
/sys/module/i915/parameters/vbt_sdvo_panel_type=-1
```

Here is what `modinfo -p i915` says:

```
modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=DRM_I915_KMS from .config, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)
panel_ignore_lid:Override lid status (0=autodetect, 1=autodetect disabled [default], -1=force lid closed, -2=force lid open) (int)
powersave:Enable powersavings, fbc, downclocking, etc. (default: true) (int)
semaphores:Use semaphores for inter-ring sync (default: -1 (use per-chip defaults)) (int)
enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6. Different stages can be selected via bitmask values (0 = disable; 1 = enable rc6; 2 = enable deep rc6; 4 = enable deepest rc6). For example, 3 would enable rc6 and deep rc6, and 7 would enable everything. default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int)
lvds_downclock:Use panel (LVDS/eDP) downclocking for power savings (default: false) (int)
lvds_channel_mode:Specify LVDS channel mode (0=probe BIOS [default], 1=single-channel, 2=dual-channel) (int)
lvds_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int)
vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override/Ignore selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (-2=ignore, -1=auto [default], index in VBT BIOS table) (int)
reset:Attempt GPU resets (default: true) (bool)
enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool)
enable_ppgtt:Override PPGTT usage. (-1=auto [default], 0=disabled, 1=aliasing, 2=full) (int)
enable_psr:Enable PSR (default: false) (int)
preliminary_hw_support:Enable preliminary hardware support. (int)
disable_power_well:Disable the power well when possible (default: true) (int)
enable_ips:Enable IPS (default: true) (int)
fastboot:Try to skip unnecessary mode sets at boot time (default: false) (bool)
prefault_disable:Disable page prefaulting for pread/pwrite/reloc (default:false). For developers only. (bool)
invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int)
disable_display:Disable display (default: false) (bool)
disable_vtd_wa:Disable all VT-d workarounds (default: false) (bool)
enable_cmd_parser:Enable command parsing (1=enabled [default], 0=disabled) (int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution for you.
I just wanted to point out that from the output of lspci and lshw, you seem to have not one but **two** graphic cards.

the second not being initialised by any driver:

> *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
>
> configuration: latency=0

Edit:
and a place to look for more information is **/var/log/Xorg.0.log**, and the other log files like **/var/log/syslog** (or the ouput of *dmesg* command) to look for errors or warning or whatever that could help find a solution

Comment: Actually, I just ran `lshw` while booted into Lucid 10.04 (2.6.35-32-generic kernel) where LVDS1 and VGA1 both work normally and got almost exactly the same output as before (including `*-display:1 UNCLAIMED` and `configuration:latency=0`). So I'm not sure anymore that those are indicative of problems. The only difference from the 3.13.0-39-generic kernel (where LVDS1 isn't working and won't accept mode settings from `xrandr`) is that `vga_controller` is missing from the `capabilities:` line of the `lshw -c video` output when booted into the 2.6.35-32-generic kernel